# How to use uppercase with zref?

Tags: zref, uppercase

I would like to use the command `\makefirstuc` (from the package `mfirstuc`) to capitalize the first letter of what is printed by the command `\ztitleref` (from the package `zref`). It doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[user,titleref]{zref}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\newcommand{\saveRef}[2]{%
    \ztitlerefsetup{title={#2}}\zlabel{#1}
}

\newcommand{\printRef}[1]{%
    The \ul{\mbox{\ztitleref{#1}}} is on page \zpageref{#1}.
}

\newcommand{\printRefUpper}[1]{%
    The \makefirstuc{{\ul{\mbox{\ztitleref{#1}}}}} is on page \zpageref{#1}.
}

\begin{document}

\saveRef{first}{first title saved}
\saveRef{second}{second title saved}

Print \textbackslash ztitleref normally (it works) :

\printRef{first}

\printRef{second}

\bigskip Print \textbackslash ztitleref with uppercase on first letter (it does not work) :

\printRefUpper{first}

\printRefUpper{second}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Does anyone know why it's not working? Any idea of how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\makefirstuc` has no chance to find the first char if you hide it in a `\ul`, `\mbox`, `ztitleref`.

You need expandable commands, and should put the titlecasing inside. With a current LaTeX (!) you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[user,titleref]{zref}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand{\saveRef}[2]{%
    \ztitlerefsetup{title={#2}}\zlabel{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mytitleref[1]{\zref@extractdefault{#1}{title}{??}}
\makeatother
\AddToNoCaseChangeList{\mytitleref}

\soulregister\MakeTitlecase{1}

\newcommand{\printRef}[1]{%
    The \ul{\mbox{\ztitleref{#1}}} is on page \zpageref{#1}.}

\newcommand{\printRefUpper}[1]{%
    The \ul{\MakeTitlecase{\mytitleref{#1}} is on page \mbox{\zpageref{#1}}.}}


\begin{document}

\saveRef{first}{first title saved}
\saveRef{second}{second title saved}

Print \textbackslash ztitleref normally (it works) :

\printRef{first}

\printRef{second}

\bigskip Print \textbackslash ztitleref with uppercase on first letter:

\printRefUpper{first}

\printRefUpper{second}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you Ulrike for this quick response. It's really generous to share your expertise like that. I really appreciate it. It answers my question very well. Have a great day! :)